# Getting errors when trying to generate file C++

Tags: c++, file, file-format, ofstream

I basically what to export text into a file format of my own.

I decided to come up with an extension called '.msq', and I wanted to know how I could protect its contents. At the moment, if you open this .msq file in a text editor you can see the text - and I don't want that happening. How can go about protecting it?

Another error I am getting is that I am unable to name my file. I am getting this error

```
no matching function for call to 
'std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string<char>)'
ofstream examplefile (file_name+".msq");
```

Basically, `file_name` is a variable that stores the userinput. This is the code that does this,

```
string file_name = getline(cin, name), where name is the input given by the user
```

As for protecting the '.msq' file, how would I go about doing that

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/
ofstream constructor expects a `const char *` as filename, not a string. First create the string and then use `file_name.c_str()`.

About protecting the file, saving it as binary could do the trick.

Comment: Protection of the data is not a black/white issue.  Protection should be considered in levels or degrees.  For example, encryption would add some protection, but advanced hackers could still read it.  Remember, the better the protection, the more difficult the data is to use.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. You seem to have two questions here, I'd suggest you edit the post and ask just one, then post the other as a new question.

Comment: getline() returns an istream and not a string (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline).  Could you please provide your real code (at least one which compiles) ?

Comment: why do you want to "protect" your file? Are you worried about people reading it or people writing to it?

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. Thank you for the `file_name.c_str()`  suggestion @JaviV. I am new to this forum, and I really appreciate the generosity and effort you have all given to help me. Much appreciated. I don't want the user to be able to see the plain string text in my file, how would I go about not displaying it as plain text?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect your file, you'll have to encrypt it.

I'd recommend the book "Applied cryptography" from Bruce Schneier on this, or if you want to go fast have a look [at blowfish implementation here](https://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html) for some source code.  Please note that cryptographic code is severly controlled by law in some countries, and you might not be authorised to download this code depending on where you reside (no joke !).

But your problem only shifted. Now that your file is encrypted, unless you use a key (password) given by the user, you'll have to embedd the key in your soruce code, and this is vulnerable to basic hacking techniques.